# using reflection to access a method return an interface in java or ikvm

Tags: java, reflection, ikvm

I'm new to java and now I want to use ikvm to acccess some classes in C#:
For example , I have this class in Java:

```
package com.mypk.js;
public class SBManager
{

    public static Session getSession(String url)   
    {
        Session session = null;

        session = createSession(url);
        return session;
    }

    private static Session createSession(String url)
    {
        Session rval = null;
        ...

        return rval;
    }
}
```

where Session is an interface like this:

```
package com.mypk.js;
import...;

public abstract interface Session
{
    public abstract void closeConnection()
    public abstract void connect()
}
```

My question is How to use ikvm reflection (or java reflection) to get SBManager instance and access its own methods or method of Session interface like I do in java like this:

```
private Session session = null;

session = SBManager.getSession("abc");

session.closeConnection();

session = null;
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To get the class instance

```
Class c = SBManager().getClass();
```

to get available methods

```
Method[] allMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
```

invoking all the methods

```
for (Method m : allMethods){
m.invoke(obj, null);  // if the calling method expects argument, instead of null you need to pass them
}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, but what is code to do do this: private Session session = null;

session = SBManager.getSession("abc");

session.closeConnection();

session = null;